# Checking if HTML select element is empty

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following select element in HTML:

```
<div id="myselect">
    Results
    <select></select>
</div>
```

And I populate it with data from a database if any and then I want to check if it contains any elements, so I do:

```
var myselect = d3.select('#myselect select');
var r = myselect.datum();
if(r.option.length != 0) {
    ...
}
```

The issue here is that `myselect` is an array which I know only has one element. I thought `datum()` was the way to get that value but this makes `r` null.

Comment: Try F12 and console.log(myselect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [selection.empty()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#empty) to determine whether or not a selection is empty.

```
const isEmpty = d3.selectAll("div").empty();
```

For you're particular example you probably want something more like this. What you're doing is checking whether the selection is empty or not, and then grabbing the actual `HTMLElement` from within that selection using  [selection.node()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#node).

```
var myselect = d3.select('#myselect select');
if (!myselect.empty()) {
    var node = myselect.node();
    var options = node.options;
    if (options.length > 0) {

    }
}
```

The `datum()` function is used differently, that will return the data object that the selection has been bound to. For example if you did:

```
d3.selectAll("div")
  .data(["A", "B", "C"])
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d; }); // will return a letter

// Go select a div and grab the data object it's bound to
// which will return the array item "B", but this could have
// equally been a complex object
d3.select("div.B").datum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to get the raw HTMLSelectElement for your `<select>`. Try using [`.node()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_node):

```
var myselect = d3.select('#myselect select');
var r = myselect.node();
if (r.options.length != 0) { // options, not option?
    ...
}
```